# How to use Spring Prototype Scope and custom bean name?

Tags: spring

I have 3 classes, lets say, ClassA, ClassB, ClassC that are going to collaborate over an use case, so let say my use case defines over an 'id' and 'source' fields an unique key, so for every unique combination of 'id', 'source' there will be instances InstanceA_id1_source1, InstanceB_id1_source1, InstanceC_id1_source1, ....(n)...

I am trying to inject a Bean to 'InstanceA_id1_source1, InstanceB_id1_source1, InstanceC_id1_source1' that will only exist for combination of 'id1' and 'source1'...

So my idea was to create with a bean with Prototype Scope for 'id1' and 'source1' and inject it to 'InstanceA_id1_source1, InstanceB_id1_source1, InstanceC_id1_source1' with a special name...

I managed to create the Bean in protoype mode..

```
@Component
class Config {
  @Bean
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public ReceptionFacade someFacade(String id, String source) {
    return new SomeFacade(id, source);
  }
}
```

And I can get Instance at the class at 'InstanceA_id1_source1, InstanceB_id1_source1, InstanceC_id1_source1'....

```
@Autowired
BeanFactory beanFactory;

SomeFacade someFacade =
    beanFactory.getBean(SomeFacade.class, id, source);
```

this works and I get for every call a different instance of the SomeFacade as expected from Prototype scope but what I wanted was to register this bean as 'someFacade_id1_source1' to Spring Context so I can re-inject it again with the following...

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
@Qualifer("someFacade_id1_source1")
SomeFacade someFacade;
```

but I can't find a way to influence the choice for the bean name in Spring, it seems there were some ideas [Naming Strategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0-m2/reference/html/naming-strategy.html) but those were abandoned and 'AnnotationBeanNameGenerator' decides the Bean Name I can' influence this procedure...

Any idea how to achieve what I like to do?

Comment: You could and it still wouldn't work. Prototype scope will give each injection point a new instance. If that isn't what you want define the number of beans you need, with a specific name you want to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a qualifier name to your bean and then use it to pick the bean you want.

Something like this should work:

```java
@Configuration
class Config {
  @Bean(name = "someFacade_id1_source1")
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public ReceptionFacade someFacade(String id, String source) {
    return new SomeFacade(id, source);
  }
}

@Service
class SomeService {
  @Autowired
  @Lazy
  @Qualifer("someFacade_id1_source1")
  SomeFacade someFacade;

}
```

Comment: The point you are missing, I don't want to hard code the Qualifier, I want it to dynamically created from my id, source combination... so if my use case dictate a id2, source2 exist, then bean should be named 'someFacade_id2_source2'

Comment: I see, then you might need to implement the `BeanFactoryAware` to declare your beans and autowire them using a `Map`, I'll edit my answer.